# How to map multiple objects to single object while one object may be null?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm looking for the best way to map the query result to a single object, preferably an EmailDto. Everything would be fine while use `dapper`, but here is the catch - `EmailAttached` can be null.

Structure of EmailDto is:

```
public class EmailDto
    {
        public Guid EmailId { get; set; }
        public Guid EmailAccountId { get; set; }
        public string EmailName { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Receiver { get; set; }
        public EmailAccountDto EmailAccount { get; set; }
        public List<EmailAttachedDto> EmailAttached { get; set; }
    }
```

and the query:

```
var sqlQuery = "SELECT " +
                        $"Email.EmailId AS {nameof(EmailDto.EmailId)}, " +
                        $"Email.EmailAccountId AS {nameof(EmailDto.EmailAccountId)}, " +
                        $"Email.EmailName AS {nameof(EmailDto.EmailName)}, " +
                        $"Email.Subject AS {nameof(EmailDto.Subject)}, " +
                        $"Email.Content AS {nameof(EmailDto.Content)}, " +
                        $"Email.Receiver AS {nameof(EmailDto.Receiver)}, " +
                        $"EmailAttached.EmailAttachedId AS {nameof(EmailAttachedDto.EmailAttachedId)}, " +
                        $"EmailAttached.EmailId AS {nameof(EmailAttachedDto.EmailId)}, " +
                        $"EmailAttached.FilePath AS {nameof(EmailAttachedDto.FilePath)}, " +
                        $"EmailAttached.Name AS {nameof(EmailAttachedDto.Name)}, " +
                        $"EmailAccount.EmailAccountId AS {nameof(EmailAccountDto.EmailAccountId)}, " +
                        $"EmailAccount.Name AS {nameof(EmailAccountDto.Name)}, " +
                        $"EmailAccount.EmailAddress AS {nameof(EmailAccountDto.EmailAddress)}, " +
                        $"EmailAccount.SmtpServer AS {nameof(EmailAccountDto.SmtpServer)}, " +
                        $"EmailAccount.SmtpPort AS {nameof(EmailAccountDto.SmtpPort)}, " +
                        $"EmailAccount.SmtpLogin AS {nameof(EmailAccountDto.SmtpLogin)}, " +
                        $"EmailAccount.SmtpPassword AS {nameof(EmailAccountDto.SmtpPassword)} " +
                        $"FROM Commander_Email AS Email " +
                        $"LEFT JOIN Commander_EmailAccount AS EmailAccount ON Email.EmailAccountId = EmailAccount.EmailAccountId " +
                        $"LEFT JOIN Commander_EmailAttached AS EmailAttached ON Email.EmailId = EmailAttached.EmailId " +
                        "WHERE Email.ProcessedDate IS NULL";
```

I have access here to IDBConnection so i was trying with dapper for example something like this:

```
dynamic emailJobs = await connection.QueryAsync<dynamic>(sqlQuery);
```

What is your proposition to map this to one object ?

Comment: Well, why not default it to an empty list? `public List<EmailAttachedDto> EmailAttached { get; set; } = new();`

Comment: Side note: consider using a verbatim string then you can embed newlines. Also use shorter table aliases to make it more readable.

Answer (score -1):

Something along these kinds of lines;

```
string TName;        
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TrialName FROM dbo.CT WHERE NumId=@Trial";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Trial", TrialId);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            TName  = reader["TrialName"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer taken from an example here, [C# SqlCommand - Setting resultset to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808915/c-sharp-sqlcommand-setting-resultset-to-a-variable)

Seems that is the kind of thing you're looking for.

In Java, it's known as a ResultSet.

Pick out the data you need and add it to the Object as you would normally do. I'm not as familiar with C# specifics and syntax, but you get the idea. It's basically that.